# Update data from a WITH clause on SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a table **property **with records of postgis coordinates column **geoarea**(Points), and a bool column **within_area**(Bool) to determine whether its inside of that another postgis **st_union**(Polygon) from table **urbanArea**

```
select properties.id, ST_Within(properties.geoarea,st_transform("urbanArea"."st_union",2393)) from properties,"urbanArea"
```

which returns me all the records in properties by id, and bool value if its within the area or not. It takes about 10 sec to execute the query

I would like to now get the values from that select statement and insert it into the ****within_area**** column, I came up with this SQL query but it hangs forever and doesnt finish, any idea why?

```
UPDATE properties p
SET  within_area = (
with newarea as (select properties.id, ST_Within(properties.geoarea,st_transform("urbanArea"."st_union",2393)) as "isInside" from properties,"urbanArea")
select u."isInside" from newarea u  where u.id = p.id
)
```

I've as well tried doing it with CTE yet it still hangs forever.

```
with newarea as (select properties.id, ST_Within(properties.geoarea,st_transform("urbanArea"."st_union",2393)) from properties, "urbanArea")
UPDATE properties
SET 
    withinurban=newa.st_within
FROM properties prop
INNER JOIN
newarea newa
ON prop.id = newa.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra join to `properties` in your 2nd query:

```
WITH newarea AS (
  SELECT p.id, 
         ST_Within(p.geoarea, ST_Transform(u."st_union", 2393)) st_within
  FROM properties p, "urbanArea" u
)
UPDATE properties p
SET withinurban = n.st_within
FROM newarea n
WHERE p.id = n.id;
```

But, your code seems equivalent to just:

```
UPDATE properties p
SET withinurban = ST_Within(p.geoarea, ST_Transform(u."st_union", 2393))
FROM "urbanArea" u;
```

or:

```
UPDATE properties p
SET withinurban = ST_Within(p.geoarea, ST_Transform((SELECT "st_union" FROM "urbanArea"), 2393));
```

Comment: The queries do seem to execute but they keep hanging indefinitely. What could the cause of this be?

Comment: @BitByte the functions `ST_Within()` and `ST_Transform()` are not standard SQLite functions so I can't say about their performance when used with SQLite. You say that the SELECT query takes 10 secs to finish and this is indicative that just a full table scan like that is not fast at all. Try to update the table in chunks. Add a `WHERE p.id < 1000` (or any other limit) to the queries and see what happens.